# Rotate two images with compass on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am trying to rotate two images in my app, one of which points north and the other points to a specified coordinate.

The code for calculating the bearing between these points is in `viewDidLoad` and is:

```
//start updating compass
locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
locationManager.delegate=self;
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

//get coords of current location
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D fromLoc = [location coordinate];

//mecca:
CLLocationCoordinate2D toLoc = [location coordinate];
toLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.4167, 39.8167);


//calculate the bearing between current location and Mecca

    float fLat = degreesToRadians(fromLoc.latitude);
    float fLng = degreesToRadians(fromLoc.longitude);
    float tLat = degreesToRadians(toLoc.latitude);
    float tLng = degreesToRadians(toLoc.longitude);

    float degree = radiandsToDegrees(atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)));

    if (degree >= 0) {
        bearing  = degree;
    } else {
        bearing = degree+360;
    }
```

And the code for animating the images is:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {

    //compass
    float oldRad =  -manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
    float newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
    CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRad];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRad];
    theAnimation.duration = 0.3f;
    [compassImage.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
    compassImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
    NSLog(@"%f (%f) => %f (%f)", manager.heading.trueHeading, oldRad, newHeading.trueHeading, newRad);


    //needle
    //float MoldRad =  (-manager.heading.trueHeading - bearing) * M_PI / 180.0f; //tried this, but it causes needle to spin a lot
    float MnewRad =  (180 + bearing) * M_PI / 180.0f;
    theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:MoldRad];
    theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:MnewRad];
    theAnimation.duration = 0.6f;
    [needleImage.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateMyRotation"];
    needleImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(MnewRad);
    MoldRad = MnewRad;
    NSLog(@"%f (%f) => %f (%f)", manager.heading.trueHeading, MoldRad, newHeading.trueHeading, MnewRad);

}
```

The compass rotates perfectly, but the needle does not always. It loads correctly first, but does not turn as the app does. I think this is something to do with it not being recalculated, but can't work out how to remember its 'old' position so it can animate correctly.

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't animate the rotation.

Just change the rotation when you get a notification from CoreMotion that the orientation has changed.

It happens so often that the changes will be very small and so it will look smith without using an animation at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to remove previous Animations before adding new one in.

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations]
```